# Strange behavior of semicolon in Coq

Tags: coq

I'm having a problem understanding why my Coq code doesn't do what I expect in the code below.

- I tried to make the example as simplified as possible, but the problem didn't show up anymore when I made it even simpler.
- It's using CompCert 1.8 files.
- This happened to me under Coq 8.2-pl2.

Here is the code:

```
Require Import Axioms.
Require Import Coqlib.
Require Import Integers.
Require Import Values.
Require Import Asm.

Definition foo (ofs: int) (c: code) : Prop :=
  c <> nil /\ ofs <> Int.zero.

Inductive some_prop: nat -> Prop :=
| some_prop_ctor :
  forall n other_n ofs c lo hi ofs_ra ofs_link,
    some_prop n ->
    foo ofs c ->
    find_instr (Int.unsigned ofs) c <> Some (Pallocframe lo hi ofs_ra ofs_link) ->
    find_instr (Int.unsigned ofs) c <> Some (Pfreeframe lo hi ofs_ra ofs_link) ->
    some_prop other_n
.

Lemma simplified:
  forall n other_n ofs c,
  some_prop n ->
  foo ofs c ->
  find_instr (Int.unsigned ofs) c = Some Pret ->
  some_prop other_n.
Proof.
  intros.
```

This does not work:

```
  eapply some_prop_ctor
    with (lo:=0) (hi:=0) (ofs_ra:=Int.zero) (ofs_link:=Int.zero);
      eauto; rewrite H1; discriminate.
```

Fails on `rewrite H1` with:

```
Error:
Found no subterm matching "find_instr (Int.unsigned ofs) c" in the current goal.
```

This works though:

```
  eapply some_prop_ctor
    with (lo:=0) (hi:=0) (ofs_ra:=Int.zero) (ofs_link:=Int.zero);
      eauto.
  rewrite H1; discriminate.
  rewrite H1; discriminate.
Qed.
```

Also, just after the `eauto`, my goal looks like this:

```
2 subgoals
n : nat
other_n : nat
ofs : int
c : code
H : some_prop n
H0 : foo ofs c
H1 : find_instr (Int.unsigned ofs) c = Some Pret
______________________________________(1/2)
find_instr (Int.unsigned ofs) c <> Some (Pallocframe 0 0 Int.zero Int.zero)


______________________________________(2/2)
find_instr (Int.unsigned ofs) c <> Some (Pfreeframe 0 0 Int.zero Int.zero)
```

So, `rewrite H1; discriminate` twice works, but "piping" it after `eauto` using a semicolon doesn't work.

I hope the problem makes sense at least. Thank you!

---

Full code:

```
Require Import Axioms.
Require Import Coqlib.
Require Import Integers.
Require Import Values.
Require Import Asm.

Definition foo (ofs: int) (c: code) : Prop :=
  c <> nil /\ ofs <> Int.zero.

Inductive some_prop: nat -> Prop :=
| some_prop_ctor :
  forall n other_n ofs c lo hi ofs_ra ofs_link,
    some_prop n ->
    foo ofs c ->
    find_instr (Int.unsigned ofs) c <> Some (Pallocframe lo hi ofs_ra ofs_link) ->
    find_instr (Int.unsigned ofs) c <> Some (Pfreeframe lo hi ofs_ra ofs_link) ->
    some_prop other_n
.

Lemma simplified:
  forall n other_n ofs c,
  some_prop n ->
  foo ofs c ->
  find_instr (Int.unsigned ofs) c = Some Pret ->
  some_prop other_n.
Proof.
  intros.
(*** This does not work:
  eapply some_prop_ctor
    with (lo:=0) (hi:=0) (ofs_ra:=Int.zero) (ofs_link:=Int.zero);
      eauto; rewrite H1; discriminate.
***)
  eapply some_prop_ctor
    with (lo:=0) (hi:=0) (ofs_ra:=Int.zero) (ofs_link:=Int.zero);
      eauto.    
  rewrite H1; discriminate.
  rewrite H1; discriminate.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, this might be an answer to my own question (thanks to someone on #coq IRC channel):

It could be the case that the unification of existential variables doesn't happen until the `.`
Therefore, by semicolon-ing, I might have prevented the `ofs` and `c` from being unified.

What I found out though is that writing `...; eauto; subst; rewrite H1; discriminate.` will work. `subst` would in this case force the unification of the existential variables, hence unlocking the ability to rewrite.